# Javascript Regex exclude matches that contain keywords

Tags: regex

I'm trying to do a single javascript regex that matches email addresses that start with `lcp_` but ignore any matches that also contain the word `auto` at any position.

I've tried a few things with no luck

```
/^lcp[._-](?!auto)/gi
```

The goal is following
`lcp_land@blah.com` - match
`lcp_land_auto@blah.com` - no match

Thanks

Comment: What if you do it with multiple regular expressions instead? 1 expression is not the target everyone should reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you use a "tempered greedy token" which basically means you are checking a negative lookahead with each repetition of the sub-pattern, so as to exclude the illegal string at any position, something like this for example:

```
\blcp_(?:(?!auto)\S)+(?=\s)
```

https://regex101.com/r/I0xisv/2

Comment: Awesome. thank you ! Do you know if it is possible to do this with multiple alternatives ?  IE: \blcp|exp|acr_(?:(?!auto)\S)+(?=\s)

Comment: np. yes, multiple starting alternations or multiple "disallowed" word alternations would work (remember to enclose them in parens)...